# Php Arrays Group and Sum

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
array(4) {
  ["Product1"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["Product2"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Product3"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Product4"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
array(4) {
  ["Product1"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["Product2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["Product3"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Product4"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

I need to group the products and sum their quantities, to have this:

```
array(4) {
  ["Product1"]=>
  string(1) "9"
  ["Product2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["Product3"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Product4"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

Sorry for my poor English, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** If you have many arrays with same keys and you have to count sum of values for each key for each array.

Use this:

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($parentArray[0] as $key => $value) {
    $property = $key;
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($parentArray as $array) {
        $value = $array[$property];
        $sum = $sum + $value;
    }
    $finalArray[$property] = $sum;
}
```

Output will be same.

[Example here](https://ideone.com/l4pasc).

Try this:

How to do what you want? Get sum:

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $value1 = $array1[$key];
    $value2 = $array2[$key];

    $finalArray[$key] = $value1 + $value2;
}
```

How to output results? Output:

```
foreach($finalArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." sum is ".$value;
}
```

Tell me if something is unclear.

Note, that `+` sign will change both values types to `integer` and you will get integer output.

If you want string output use this:

```
echo "".$integerValue;
```

P.S.: Why they are string type? Is it neccessary?

Comment: Will `$value1 + $value2` work on strings? Shouldn't `intval` be applied?

Comment: @JohnBupit it will work properly. Look this example: https://ideone.com/l4pasc

Comment: @JohnBupit, I explained it in note btw.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav I don't have only 2 arrays, can be n arrays...

Comment: How you store this arrays? Keys are equal in all arrays?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav orders, product|quantity array. This is an example: http://laravel.io/bin/WW94K

Comment: @user3574595 I updated my answer. Check the example, please. Now you can add 100 more arrays with same keys and this code will work. Does my answer help you now?

Answer (score 0):

Example code that should work with multiple input arrays of different keys

```
// 0. let's say all your arrays are in $arrays, 
$arrays[] = array(...data for array 1...);
$arrays[] = array(...data for array 2...);
$arrays[] = array(...data for array 3...); // and so on...

// 1. get all keys together from the array's

$ak = array(); // keys
$ar = array(); // result

foreach ($arrays as $array) {
  $ak = array_merge($ak, array_keys($array));
}

// 2. sum all the values for all keys into one
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
  foreach ($ak as $key) {
    $ar[$key] += $array[$key];
  }
}

// result is in $ar
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way for 2 arrays:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($firstarray as $k => $val){
    $newarray[$k] = (int)$newarray[$k] + (int) $val;
}
foreach($secondarray as $k => $val){
    $newarray[$k] = (int)$newarray[$k] + (int) $val;
}

var_dump($newarray);
```